# scope.watch sets watched model to "undefined" in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with the following code:

```
(function(window, angular, undefined) {'use strict';

angular.module('widgets.avatarEditor', [])

.controller('AvatarEditorController', [
  '$scope',
  '$attrs',
  '$timeout',
  function($scope, $attrs, $timeout) {

  }
])

.directive('avatarEditor', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      originalImage: '=originalImage'
    },
    controller: 'AvatarEditorController',
    templateUrl: '/config/static/partials/widgets/avatareditor.html',
    link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
      scope.watch('originalImage',function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
        console.log(newValue);
        console.log(oldValue);
        console.log(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});

})(window, window.angular);
```

The directive is used in an application:

Partial:

```
<avatar-editor original-image="currentPicture"></avatar-editor>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.currentPicture = 'b';

$scope.avatars = AvatarsResource.get({}, function() {
  $scope.currentPicture = 'bar';
});
```

Without the `scope.watch('originalImage',function (newValue, oldValue, scope)...` code all works fine, but when I add the watch code, suddenly the "originalImage" model is undefined.

The strage thing is, that the watch event is correctly triggered.

Has anybody any idea, what could cause this bahavior?

Edit:
I found something strange with the parameters of the listener function of watch:
newValue contains "originalImage"
oldValue contains "b" (the real old value)
context contains "bar" (the real new value)

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle example for this please? It would help to see this happening in action.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I feel stupid, now...

`scope.watch('` != `scope.$watch('`